# Extension of prime ideal in $k[V]$ to $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$ is prime?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $I\subset k[X_1,\cdots, X_n]$ be a prime ideal, $V=V(I) \subset \mathbb{A}^n$  a variety and $P=(a_1,\cdots, a_n)\in V.$ Recall that $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$ is the set of rational functions from $V$ to $k$ defined at $P.$

Suppose $J\subset k[V]$ is a prime ideal of the coordinate ring $k[V] = \dfrac{k[X_1,\cdots, X_n]}{I}$ and that $J$ is contained in the maximal ideal $ \dfrac{ (X_1-a_1, \cdots, X_n-a_n)}{I}$.

I want to show that $J' := J\mathcal{O}_P(V)$ is a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_P(V).$

---

Here is my attempt: Let $r_1, r_2 \in \mathcal{O}_P(V)$ and write $r_i = \dfrac{p_i}{q_i}$ where $p_i, q_i \in k[V]$ (this form is unique up to associates since $k[V]$ is a UFD).

Suppose $\dfrac{p_1p_2}{q_1q_2} \in J'.$ The $q_i$ are defined at $P$ so $q_1q_2\in \mathcal{O}_P(V)$ so $p_1p_2\in J'.$

Now these $p_1,p_2$ are in $k[V].$ I think I want to use the primality of $J$ to get that $p_1$ or $p_2$ is in $J'$ from which I can conclude that $J'$ is prime. But how do I get $p_1\in J'$ or $p_2\in J'$? This approach may be totally wrong, I can't see where $J$ being contained in the maximal ideal that corresponds to $P\in V$ is used.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In general, prime ideals of $A_\mathfrak{p}$ correspond 1:1 to prime ideals of $A$ contained in $\mathfrak{p}$ (you can find this in every text on commutative algebra, or prove it yourself). I think this generalization makes it easier to work with.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Is $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ the localization of $A$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ ? I will learn about localization this week, but this problem is from a section of Fulton's [Algebraic Curves](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) that does not assume the reader knows about localization. Is there a more direct argument that works for this particular case?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I found the statement you mentioned in Atiyah-Macdonald and it is only a few pages into the chapter so I will just start learning about localization and see how to translate it into a direct proof when I've done that. Thank you for your guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition that $J$ is contained in the maximal ideal corresponding to $P$ ensures that $J':=J \mathcal{O}_P(V)$ is not all of $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$. This is a necessary condition for $J'$ to be a prime ideal, since $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$ is not considered a prime ideal of itself.

Also, it is not true that $k[V]$ is always a UFD (consider for example $V=V(xy-zw) \subset \Bbb{A}^4$).

But basically, your attempt at solving the problem is correct. Assume that
$$
\frac{p_1}{q_1} \cdot \frac{p_2}{q_2} \in J'.
$$

Multiplying by $q_1q_2$, and using that $J'$ is an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$ yields that $p_1p_2 \in J'$. But $p_1p_2 \in J$ by the definition of $J'$ (see edit below), hence $p_1 \in J$ or $p_2 \in J$, since $J$ is prime. This shows that $\frac{p_1}{q_1} \in J'$ or $\frac{p_2}{q_2} \in J'$.

**EDIT:**
You are right, this step is not completely immediate. Thanks for pointing that out.

Assume that 
$$
\frac{p_1p_2}{q_1q_2}=\frac{p}{q_1q_2} \cdot r
$$
with $p \in J$, $r \in \mathcal{O}_P(V)$. Write $r=\frac{f}{g}$ with $f,g \in k[V]$, $g(P) \neq 0$. Then
$$
\frac{p_1p_2}{q_1q_2}=\frac{p'}{q}
$$
where $p':=p \cdot f \in J$ and $q:=q_1q_2 \cdot g$.

Now the above equality implies that $p_1p_2 \cdot q=p' \cdot q_1q_2$ in $k[V]$. The right hand side is contained in $J$, hence so is the left hand side. Now $J$ is a prime ideal, therefore $p_1p_2 \in J$, or $q \in J$. But the latter is impossible, because $q \notin (X_1-a_1,...,X_n-a_n)/I \supset J$. Thus we must have $p_1p_2 \in J$.

Comment: The crucial step I couldn't do is $p_1p_2\in J' \implies xp_1p_2\in J.$ We can say that $p_1 p_2 = P R$ where $P\in J$ and $R\in \mathcal{O}_P (V).$ But we need to show $R$ is actually a polynomial to deduce $p_1p_2 \in J,$ and that step doesn't seem immediate.

Comment: Dear @KatieDobbs, I edited my answer to clarify this point.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome, Katie.